# Consecutive records with a condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, psql

```sql
Create table  weather_forecast (
date date,
temperature decimal,
avg_humidity decimal,
avg_dewpoint decimal, 
avg_barometer decimal,
avg_windspeed decimal,
avg_gutspeed decimal,
avg_direction decimal
, rainfall_month decimal
, rainfall_year decimal
, maxrain_permin decimal
, max_temp decimal
, min_temp decimal
, max_humidity decimal,
min_humidity decimal
, max_pressure decimal
, min_pressure decimal
, max_winspeed decimal
, max_gutspeed decimal
, maxheat_index decimal
, month int
, diff_pressure decimal(7,5) 
);
```

If the maximum gust speed increases from 55mph, I need to fetch the details for the next 4 days. I am able to go this far only:

```sql
with t1 as(
select max_gutspeed, date
from weather_forecast
where max_gutspeed >55 )
, t2 as (
    select date, row_number() over () as rn
    from weather_forecast)
 select distinct(rn), t1.date, t1.max_gutspeed
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.date = t2.date
order by t2.rn asc`
```

Also, how do I find the maximum and minimum number of days when temperature dropped?

I tried doing it with the temp tables but i am stuck and don't know the next steps.

Comment: **1)** You can select only the dates when your condition was met, call them `trigger_date`, then get all dates within 4 days after that, using `where date>=trigger_date and date<=trigger_date+'4 days'::interval`. **2)** Is "next 4 days" supposed to mean exactly the next 96 hours? *"maximum and minimum number of days when temperature dropped"* sounds like a gaps and islands problem, if you mean you want to find N longest continuous periods when the `max_gutspeed` value exceeded 55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a [`daterange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) out of your `date` and an `interval` of 4 days after that. Then list everything that's on a "date" contained [`<@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) in [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) of those ranges. [online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bLYB2igxduJLhKFJKDPxsZ/2)

```sql
select * 
from weather_forecast t
where date <@ ANY(
   select daterange(date, (date+'4 days'::interval)::date, '[]')
   from weather_forecast
   where max_gutspeed >55 )
order by t.rn asc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But It is giving most of the undesirous records also. See the records from 8 to 19. Besides not having any value greater than 55 the values are still showing. Please see the image link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NP6ZkEx7nd5w-Z8VRtNiYsOxE_-1U422/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *"If the maximum gust speed increases from 55mph, I need to fetch the details for the next 4 days"* I understood it that for any record meeting the criteria you want that record, plus anything that comes within the 4 day period after that, regardless of what's in those additional 4 days. Can you re-phrase the logic?

Comment: Yes, Sure. When for a record the max_gutspeed >55. Fetch the next 4 records. Thanks

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if you're maybe looking at an outdated output from some other query. You can see in my [online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bLYB2igxduJLhKFJKDPxsZ/2) the query isn't taking anything outside the range (e.g. 1 and 7 aren't returned).